# How to remove broken installations?

Tags: release-freya, vlc

Recently I tried to install  VLC through Software center. But due to internet problem, it was errored while installing.  Now its giving trouble. So I need to remove it then I want to install a fresh copy of it.

Comment: can you add error message? What is "trouble"? Also add output of `apt-cache policy vlc`

Comment: Good, you can write your own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I installed `Synaptic Package Manager` from software center. You can install it through software center or using the following command on your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Than I tried to fix using synaptic.  But it doest not solve my problem and again it's not installing Vlc player. So I used the following command to Fix it.

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

After that Vlc installed. But it doesnot open. So I moved to get another command to fix the broken installation again.

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

The above command fixed it and than its working fine now.

Comment: FYI: The `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing` is not correct, `The update command takes no arguments`, probably that is `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` :)

Comment: I read some where in askubuntu and solved it. Whether it works or not. But my problem solved.  That's it.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you needed to install synaptic.

Comment: I thought to remove.  But it's not working.  So fixing it through synaptic and tried to work again.

Comment: " fixing it through synaptic"--In your answer, you just installed `synaptic` but not used it anywhere. You can run the last commands, without having(installing) `syaptic`

Comment: Updated my answer now. The steps I tried I wrote here.  And the final one was helped to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Install `synaptic` from software center.

Open synaptic and *Edit* --> *Fix broken packages*

[image: Imgur]

- One of the most basic fixes to resolve dependencies problems is to run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```

Comment: Will keep it remember and work on following days.